# Ubuntu 16.04 static IP

Tags: networking, 16.04, server, network-manager

Ubuntu beginner trying to improve Linux / Ubuntu skills.

I've setup a new VM and trying to configure a static IP.

When I set a new static IP on ubuntu (/etc/network/interfaces)I have to reset it's MAC address in order for it to work (restarting the network service won't work). Is there a way to remove MAC address association like in CentoOS ?

Thanks and regards,
J

Comment: What do you mean by "reset its MAC address"? Normally you just add the interface to `/etc/network/interfaces` with a static IP address and reboot.

Comment: I'm trying to eliminate the part where you 'reboot'. In ubuntu 14.04 a simple /etc/init.d/networking restart applies the new IP configuration however on 16.04 this is not possible.

On CentOS it was possible to eliminate the HWADDR from the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 file, however it does not seem to be possible in ubuntu

Comment: That's tricky. Adding an interface to `/etc/network/interfaces` takes it out of the realm of NetworkManager. I haven't tried it, but the following sequence may work: down the interface, stop NetworkManager (which still manages the interface), add the stanza to `/etc/network/interfaces`, start Network Manager (now no longer attempts to manage the interface), up the interface.

Comment: @AlexP Network manager is not currently installed (I'm using a minimal version of Ubuntu 16.04 and network manager doesn't seem to be pre-installed).

Comment: And what happens if you `sudo systemctl restart network`? Or just `ifdown`, `ip addr flush dev`, `ifup`?

Comment: systemctl restart network gives me the error gives me the error "failed to restart network.service: Unit network.service not found". however ifdown > ipaddr flush dev > if up solved my problem and I was able to change static IP without reboot. Thanks @AlexP. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll mark it as fixed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a minimal install with no NetworkManager, you can restart your network interface by running `ifdown`, `ip addr flush dev` and `ifup` on the interface in this sequence. You may want to take the relevant precautions if you are connected through SSH...